# What interface do modern laptop touchpads use internally?

Tags: touchpad

I want to wire up an old laptop touchpad for use with a desktop machine.  I believe older laptop touchpads used a PS/2 based interface - but what about newer ones?  Something standard?
Also, anyone know how the buttons factor in?

Comment: I remember seeing mine as connected via USB. But this was a long time ago, so this might have changed.

Comment: Yep, usb the vast majority of the time.

Comment: It might help to get some info on the touchpad. You may need to do some mods to get it usable by a standard ps/2 connector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its safe to say that USB is the connection of choice for most internal add ons for modern laptops. Check hardware profiling software tools and manufacturer repair specifications to be sure. Additionally while the devices may be USB you will need to adapt and add on a tradition USB plug to be used externally, since pretty much all internal devices do not share the same connectors as their external counterparts. That will require you to do some wire and pin identification to wire it up properly to an external USB cable and plug.

The buttons should just factor in along with the trackpad, usually on the same circuit board for the track pad, acting together to act just as a standard mouse-like input device would.